# NumPy exponential of MPC's arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mpmath

I'm trying to define the exponential of the wave equation which is `e^(ik(x-ct))`.
This is new for me, so I'm trying to understand MPC's arrays with real and imaginary numbers, and what do they mean. I'm trying to rewrite a code originally in Matlab to Python.

`ik*(x-ct)` equals:

```
array([[[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]],

       [[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]],

       [[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]],

       ...,

       [[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]],

       [[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]],

       [[mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), ..., mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'),
         mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0'), mpc(real='0.0', imag='0.0')],
        [mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868'),
         mpc(real='3.8473413874435805e-18', imag='0.062831853071795868')],
        [mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174'),
         mpc(real='7.6946827748871609e-18', imag='0.12566370614359174')],
        ...,
        [mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883'),
         mpc(real='5.6940652534164989e-16', imag='9.2991142546257883')],
        [mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838'),
         mpc(real='5.7325386672909336e-16', imag='9.3619461076975838')],
        [mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         ...,
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793'),
         mpc(real='5.7710120811653693e-16', imag='9.4247779607693793')]]],
      dtype=object)
```

but when I try to take the exponential of `ik*(x-ct)`, it shows me the following error message:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    AttributeError: 'mpc' object has no attribute 'exp'

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-29-d001448fd085> in <module>
    ----> 1 np.exp(i*k*(x - c*t))

    TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type mpc which has no callable exp method
```

I'm still confused of what I'm looking at, so I dont know where to start looking. Any recommendations?

Comment: Your numpy array contains `mpc` objects; as such its `dtype` is object.  `exp(arr)` on a object dtype array delegates the action to the `exp` method of each item.  That kind of delegation usually works for things like add and multiply, but `exp` and `sin` are usually implemented as functions, not methods.

Comment: @ hpaulj  How can I go around this problem, because in order to calculate the wave equation I need to do this?

Comment: You may have to use a list comprehension on a list of these `mpc` objects.  But do these numbers really have to be `mps/mpmath`?  What wrong with normal numeric numpy arrays?